# How do I get the connection string of notification hub in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-notificationhub

I created a notification hub with terraform. Now I need to use the connection string of the notification hub in an Azure function, but I do not understand how to get it.

Here the code where I create my notification hub:

```
resource "azurerm_notification_hub_namespace" "notifications_ntfns" {
  name                = "${var.env_prefix}-my-ntfns"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_notifications.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_notifications.location
  namespace_type      = "NotificationHub"
  sku_name            = "Free"
}

resource "azurerm_notification_hub" "notifications_ntf-carriers" {
  name                = "${var.env_prefix}-ntf-carriers"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_notification_hub_namespace.notifications_ntfns.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_notifications.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_notifications.location

  gcm_credential { ... }

  apns_credential { ... }
}

resource "azurerm_notification_hub_authorization_rule" "notifications-ntf-carriers-rules" {
  name                  = "push-management-auth-rule"
  notification_hub_name = azurerm_notification_hub.notifications_ntf-carriers.name
  namespace_name        = azurerm_notification_hub_namespace.notifications_ntfns.name
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg_notifications.name
  manage                = false
  send                  = false
  listen                = true
}
```

Now I create my azure function that should refer to the notification hub:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "notifications_func_push" {
  name                       = "${var.env_prefix}-notifications-push"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg_notifications.name
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.rg_notifications.location

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.st_notifications.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.st_notifications.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.notifications_func_plan_push.id

  enabled            = true 
  https_only         = true

  app_settings = {
    ...
    Notification_HubConnectionString = azurerm_notification_hub_authorization_rule.notifications-ntf-carriers-rules.primary_access_key  #azurerm_notification_hub_namespace.notifications_ntfns.servicebus_endpoint

    Notification_HubName             = azurerm_notification_hub.notifications_ntf-carriers.name
  }

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      dotnet_version              = "7.0"
      use_dotnet_isolated_runtime = true
    }

    always_on         = false
    http2_enabled     = true
    use_32_bit_worker = false
  }
}
```

As you can see I tried to get the connection string with

`Notification_HubConnectionString = azurerm_notification_hub_authorization_rule.notifications-ntf-carriers-rules.primary_access_key`

or

`Notification_HubConnectionString = azurerm_notification_hub_namespace.notifications_ntfns.servicebus_endpoint`

Both are wrong.

In 1st case I get just the signature key; in the second case I get just the endpoint with `https` protocol.

What I need is the connection string in this form:

`Endpoint=<endpoint_with_sb_protocol>;SharedAccessKeyName=<notification_hub_auth_rule_name>;SharedAccessKey=<access_key>`

Here, the reference I am watching:

- [azurerm_notification_hub_authorization_rule](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/notification_hub_authorization_rule#attributes-reference)
- [azurerm_notification_hub_namespace](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/notification_hub_namespace#attributes-reference)
- [azurerm_notification_hub](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/notification_hub#attributes-reference)

Nothing seems to have the connection string as output. Is it possible? How can I get it?

Thnak you

Answer (score 0):

In this case you probably need to build this string yourself, something like this (I left x for you to figure out, because this needs to probably come from the azurerm_notification_hub_authorization_rule element as well):

```
app_settings = {
    ...
    Notification_HubConnectionString = "Endpoint=${azurerm_notification_hub_namespace.notifications_ntfns.servicebus_endpoint};SharedAccessKeyName=${x};SharedAccessKey=${azurerm_notification_hub_authorization_rule.notifications-ntf-carriers-rules.primary_access_key}"

    Notification_HubName             = azurerm_notification_hub.notifications_ntf-carriers.name
  }
```